# Tab activo por defecto en formulario de búsqueda

Tags: active, tab

Tengo un formulario de búsqueda de propiedades y para las opciones de venta y alquiler están en pestañas (tabs) para seleccionar una opción hay que hacer click sobre la pestaña deseada y lo que quiero es que por defecto esté seleccionada o activa la pestaña de " En Venta" para que la búsqueda se realice con la opción "En Venta" a menos que haga click en "En Alquiler"

El código es este:

```
<ul class="status-tabs nav nav-pills justify-content-center" role="tablist" data-toggle="buttons">

<?php
$terms_status = get_terms(
    array(
        'property_status'
    ),
    array(
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'order'         => 'SCA',
        'hide_empty'    => true,
        'parent' => 0
    )
);
if (!empty($terms_status)) {
    $i = 0;      
    foreach ($terms_status as $status) { 

        if($i == my_option('tabs_limit')) {
            break;
        }
        echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-val="'.esc_attr($status->slug).'" data-toggle="pill" href="#" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
                    '.esc_attr($status->name).'
                </a>
            </li>';
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="status[]" id="search-tabs">
</ul>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]